# drush sql-sync tries to rsync unknown dump file

Tags: drush

Since I upgraded drush 5.10 -> 7.0-dev today, sql-sync fails to work with my existing alias file.

Using the command `drush sql-sync @limelive @limedev` fails.

The `%dump-dir` paths on both local and remote aliases correctly address existing directories. --debug shows the remote sql dump success:

```
 Database dump saved to /home/aegir/drush-backups/limetreethornfor/20140411235252/limetreethornfor_20140411_235252.sql.gz
```

but later reports

```
rsync: link_stat "/var/aegir/platforms/aventura-2014-04-11-1/Array" failed: No such file or directory
```

This suggest new command syntax incorrectly diagnosed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have found that Drush 7 is fine now - as long as you have the same version installed on both local and remote systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Drush master.  Please put an issue in the queue on Github.

Comment: Raised [issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/576)

Answer (score 1):

The bug has been reported [here](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/555).

I used this workaround (dump remote db and import it to local db):

```
drush @example.prod sql-dump > /tmp/example.sql
drush sql-drop -y
drush sql-query --file=/tmp/example.sql
drush cc all
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still a bug for me even in the Drush 7 stable release. I had to go back to Drush 6.6 and it works fine.

Comment: I have found that Drush 7 is fine - as long as you have the same version installed on both local and remote systems.